# Count files in MyDrive where I am the owner per GScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, drive

I try to create a script which is counting my files.

Currently I have written this Script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("GDrive");
  sheet.clear();

  for (var i = 5; i <= 13; i++) {
    //var i = 5;
    if (i == 5) {var sFT = "presentation";}
    if (i == 6) {var sFT = "form";}
    if (i == 7) {var sFT = "audio";}
    if (i == 8) {var sFT = "video";}
    if (i == 9) {var sFT = "archive";}
    if (i == 10) {var sFT = "drawing";}
    if (i == 11) {var sFT = "shortcut";}
    if (i == 12) {var sFT = "folder";}
    if (i == 13) {var sFT = "site";}

    if (i == 5) {var sTXT = "GPräsentation";}
    if (i == 6) {var sTXT = "GForm";}
    if (i == 7) {var sTXT = "Audio";}
    if (i == 8) {var sTXT = "Video";}
    if (i == 9) {var sTXT = "Archive (ZIP)";}
    if (i == 10) {var sTXT = "Zeichnungen";}
    if (i == 11) {var sTXT = "Links";}
    if (i == 12) {var sTXT = "Verzeichnisse";}
    if (i == 13) {var sTXT = "GSite";}

    if (i == 5) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners and (mimeType contains "' + MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT_LEGACY + '" or mimeType contains "' + MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT + '" or mimeType contains "' + MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES + '")');
    }

    if (i == 6) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners and (mimeType contains "' + MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS  + '")');
    }

    if (i == 7) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners and (mimeType contains "' + MimeType.Audio  + '")');
    }

    if (i == 8) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners and (mimeType contains "' + MimeType.video  + '")');
    }

    if (i == 9) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners and (mimeType contains "' + MimeType.ZIP  + '")');
    }

    if (i == 10) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners and (mimeType contains "' + MimeType.drawing  + '")');
    }

    if (i == 11) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners and (mimeType contains "' + MimeType.Links  + '")');
    }

    if (i == 12) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFolders('"me" in owners');
    }

    if (i == 13) {
    var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners and (mimeType contains "' + MimeType.GSite  + '")');
    }

    let count = 0;

    sheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(sTXT);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
   
    while (files.hasNext()) {
      var file = files.next();
      count = count +1;
    }

    sheet.getRange(i,1).setValue(i);
    sheet.getRange(i,2).setValue(sTXT);
    sheet.getRange(i,3).setValue(count);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

Link to my example-file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cR3EyK1WgF8MLniSu_O4QFUzvPQ-x3Gq9G6Y40cZr3s/edit?usp=sharing

Does anyone now why my script is not found any files for: Audio, Video, Archive (ZIP), Zeichnungen, Links, GSite but I have some files from this categories. When I search about the browser I can find all the files.

Does anyone can help?

Greetingss

Answer (score 0):

Try Some Recursion

```
function countallfiles() {
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1obWyAZl0vDlwbNqcGBq7Nt38qzusWt1d');
  getAllFilesAndFolders(folder);
  Logger.log(n);
}

var n = 0;
function getAllFilesAndFolders(folder) {
  let files = folder.getFiles();
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let file = files.next();
    if (file.getOwner().getName() == 'Your Name') {
      n++;
    }
  }
  let subfolders = folder.getFolders();
  while (subfolders.hasNext()) {
    getAllFilesAndFolders(subfolders.next());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Your script runs without any problems. It is my intention, however, that I get a submission according to MimeTypes. The feedback from Tanaike was more helpful to me, but this does not work with ZIP, audio and video.

Comment: It works for my zips and my audio but I didn't have a video in my test folder.  So it seems you still have some work to do on your part.

Comment: I know and I do my best and spend a lot of trainingtime into my project "Google-Scripting" :). My command is:     var files = DriveApp.searchFiles('"me" in owners and (mimeType contains "' + MimeType.ZIP  + '")'); - when I search about the Browser (owner:me type:archive) the system can find 4 files.

Comment: Now my script runs perfect and thanks to al. .There are some differences between the reality and the documentations. Here you can find the correct commandlines. You must use for mimeType:
for audio:
'audio/mpeg'

for video:
'video/mp4'

for drawings:
MimeType.GOOGLE_DRAWINGS

for links:
MimeType.SHORTCUT

for GSites
MimeType.GOOGLE_SITES

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the number of files every mimeType you set.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

#### Issue and solution:

About your question of `Does anyone now why my script is not found any files for: Audio, Video, Archive (ZIP), Zeichnungen, Links, GSite`, when you tested the following script,

```
var yourMimeTypes = [MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT_LEGACY, MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT, MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES, MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS, MimeType.Audio, MimeType.video, MimeType.ZIP, MimeType.drawing, MimeType.Links, MimeType.FOLDER, MimeType.GSite];
console.log(yourMimeTypes)
```

the following result is obtained.

```
[
  'application/vnd.ms-powerpoint',
  'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation',
  'application/vnd.google-apps.presentation',
  'application/vnd.google-apps.form',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  'application/zip',
  undefined,
  undefined,
  'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
  undefined
]
```

Unfortunately, in the current stage, there are no values of `MimeType.Audio, MimeType.video, MimeType.drawing, MimeType.Links, MimeType.GSite` in the enum of mimeTYpes. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type) I thought that this is the reason of your issue of `why my script is not found any files for: Audio, Video, Archive (ZIP), Zeichnungen, Links, GSite`.

From your script, for example, I guessed that you might want to use the mimeTypes as follows.

- About `MimeType.Audio`, I thought that you might want to retrieve the mimeTypes including `audio`.
- About `MimeType.video`, I thought that you might want to retrieve the mimeTypes including `video`.
- About `MimeType.ZIP`, in this case, I thought that the mimeType is different from `application/zip`. It's like `application/x-zip-compressed`. So, in this case, the mimeTypes including `zip` are retrieved.
- About `MimeType.drawing`, I thought that you might want to retrieve the mimeType of `MimeType.GOOGLE_DRAWINGS`.
- About `MimeType.Links`, I thought that you might want to retrieve the mimeType of `MimeType.SHORTCUT`.
- About `MimeType.GSite`, I thought that you might want to retrieve the mimeType of `MimeType.GOOGLE_SITES`.

When these are reflected in a script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

This script used Drive API. Because the file list is retrieved using Drive API. So, [please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please check the display names and mimeTypes of `obj`. Please modify this for your actual situation.

```js
function sample() {
  // Please set the display names and mimeTypes.
  // I created this object by guessing from your script.
  const obj = {
    "GPräsentation": [MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT_LEGACY, MimeType.MICROSOFT_POWERPOINT, MimeType.GOOGLE_SLIDES],
    "GForm": [MimeType.GOOGLE_FORMS],
    "Audio": "audio",
    "Video": "video",
    "Archive (ZIP)": "zip",
    "Zeichnungen": [MimeType.GOOGLE_DRAWINGS],
    "Links": [MimeType.SHORTCUT],
    "Verzeichnisse": [MimeType.FOLDER],
    "GSite": [MimeType.GOOGLE_SITES],
  };

  // 1. Retrieve a list of all files and folders from your Google Drive by the search query of `"me" in owners`.
  let list = [];
  let pageToken = "";
  do {
    const res = Drive.Files.list({
      q: `"me" in owners`, // I couldn't understand whether you want to use `trashed=false`. If you want to use, please add it.
      fields: "nextPageToken,items(mimeType)",
      pageToken: pageToken,
      maxResults: 1000,
      // includeItemsFromAllDrives: true, // If you want to search the files from the shared Drive, please use this.
      // supportsAllDrives: true, // If you want to search the files from the shared Drive, please use this.
    });
    if (res.items.length > 0) list = [...list, ...res.items.map(({ mimeType }) => mimeType)];
    pageToken = res.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  const mimeTypesObj = list.reduce((o, e) => (o[e] = o[e] ? o[e] + 1 : 1, o), {});
  const mimeTypesAr = Object.entries(mimeTypesObj);
  
  // 2. Create an array for putting to the sheet.
  const values = Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => {
    if (Array.isArray(v)) {
      return [k, v.reduce((c, e) => c += mimeTypesObj[e] || 0, 0)];
    }
    return [k, mimeTypesAr.reduce((c, [kk, vv]) => c += kk.includes(v.toLocaleLowerCase()) ? vv : 0, 0)];
  });

  // 3. Put the values on the sheet.
  // In this case, the values are put from "B5" from your script.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("GDrive");
  sheet.clear();
  sheet.getRange(5, 2, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
```

#### Flow:

The flow of this script is as follows.

1. Retrieve a list of all files and folders from your Google Drive by the search query of `"me" in owners`.

   - I couldn't understand whether you want to use `trashed=false`. If you want to use it, please add it.
2. Create an array for putting to the sheet.
3. Put the values on the sheet.

#### References:

- [Enum MimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type)
- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)

Comment: Hello, thanks in advance. Your support was very helpful. It is very strange but I do not get all this Mime-Variants about the Impus-Assistant. When I follow you notice it does not work with Audio, Video, ZIP. The script runs without any error but do not find any files. But there are files in myDrive. Do you have another tip for me? Or better do you have a simply example for me?

Comment: @J. Doe Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `When I follow you notice it does not work with Audio, Video, ZIP. The script runs without any error but do not find any files. But there are files in myDrive.`, in this case, those files might not be able to be retrieved by `"me" in owners`. So, when you remove `q: ``"me" in owners``,` from my script, what result will you obtain? If this was not the direct solution, can you check those files again? By the way, those files are put in the shared Drive?

Comment: @J. Doe Now, I could confirm that when I tested my proposed script for Google Drive including Audio, Video, ZIP files, those files can be retrieved. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation. So, in your situation, I'm worried that `"me" in owners` and other factors might affect your current issue. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: I could also not reproduce this last issue. For me, the ```me in owners``` correctly retrieves the desired files. Could you please provide more context or test this issue under other conditions and circumstances?

Comment: @Oriol Castander Thank you for testing my script. Now I'm trying to correctly replicate OP's situation, unfortunately, I cannot still do it. So, in this case, I hope for giving me the detailed flow for correctly replicating OP's issue by OP.